# Issue to decrypting string

Tags: c#, encryption, encoding, base64, decoding

I'm working in a project that in some point, I have to decrypt strings like this `s?\a?B???p?????` but I don't know which type of encode were used.

Here are the original string to be decode: c58HzUKIBYUfh3DVm/qa3Q==

```
string base64Encoded = "c58HzUKIBYUfh3DVm/qa3Q==";
string base64Decoded;
byte[] data = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64Encoded);
base64Decoded = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
```

And this `s?\a?B???p?????` is the result.

Someone can help me? Any type of help I would be glad!

Thanks!

Comment: One would expect `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64Encoded);` to work, but that results in a garbage string as well with that input. Are you sure the base64 is encoded text? - You say *enctypted* - what do you mean by that?

Comment: You said you have to decrypt them. There is no sign of any decryption of the bytes. Did you miss a step? Base64 is not normally considered *encryption*, just something that is done to the bytes so they can be saved as string. My guess would be, you are missing the actual decryption.

Comment: Oh well, as you can see English is not my native language, sometimes I do some confusions.

Alex, That's my doubt, I do not know which type of coding were used! If I took any string in base64, that code works. I need to know what they have used to format the string like this: c58HzUKIBYUfh3DVm/qa3Q==". The original value decrypted is teste1234!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is 16 bytes. That's precisely the output of a block cipher in ECB or CBC mode with a block size of 8 or 16 bytes. So what you get is ciphertext, which looks like random bytes. Random bytes can not be directly viewed as text, hence the question marks. You need to decrypt with a key to get the plaintext, which should be viewable as text.

Comment: They used blowfish algorithm with ECB, you are right. Thanks for the help!